# Why does passing a number when a string is expected not fail compilation

Tags: typescript

I have the following code where I am passing a number to a function which takes a string.

```
const getGreeting: Function = (name: String): String => {
    return `hello, ${name}`;
};

const x: number = 2
console.log(getGreeting(x))
```

I can understand why the outputted javascript works but why does this not result in a compilation error?

Comment: You said `getGreeting` is just `Function`. Just remove explicit type declaration. `const getGreeting = (name: String): String => {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesnt result to an error because casting your function to `Function` makes typescript to loose the details of your method.

To make it work, type properly `getGreeting` like :

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygcQE4KQSzHAXDACjAEMBbBfaVbOAShgF4A+GKmxwk8yqanWnnziMWAbwBQMKTHRQArqjAwABgAsEAGw0gANDAAkorggC+ygNziTl8aEiwAHvjBzSAIwSoOAJnG3wECAaCAB02nAEiCjoWDgEDrS0lkA)

```
const getGreeting: (name: string) => string = (name: string): string => {
    return `hello, ${name}`;
};

const x: number = 2

console.log(getGreeting(x));
```

---

Or let typescript to infer the type itself :

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=22#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygcQE4KQSzHGBeGACjAEMBbBALhmlWzgEprb78A+GAbwCgY+Z0UAK6owMAAYALBABsZIADQwAJJ1IUAvuIDc3Dbu6hIsAB7UwQsgCMEqfDABM3Q+AggZCAHTy4hRCnQsHEITBgZdIA)

```
const getGreeting = (name: string): string => {
    return `hello, ${name}`;
};

const x: number = 2

console.log(getGreeting(x));
```